# How does website detemine what's the full url when accessing resources like "/file.png"

Tags: php, laravel, web

I have a resource in my code that looks like that:

```
<img src="upload/file.jpg">
```

when I open the resource, it looks like "myapp.dev/en/upload/file.jpg"

how does the website determine  that the "base url" is "myapp.dev/en" and not "myapp.dev"? the file is accessible on "myapp.dev/upload/file.jpg" and i can hardcode it, but I want the "proper" solution.

if that helps I work with laravel

Comment: Do you have a `<base>` tag in your site…?

Comment: I have baseUrl and baseLocaleUrl, the first is the one without "en" and the latter is with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links work in the same way as paths in the OS. Links starting with `/` is relative to the root directory (your domain) if you don't have any `/` in front it is relative to the current page. So linking from `myapp.dev/en/` to `upload/file.jpg` will give `myapp.dev/en/upload/file.jpg`, linking to `/upload/file.jpg` will point to root so you get `myapp.dev/upload/file.jpg`

Hope this did explain the basics of how to get the correct file link. Laravel provides some helper functions for getting files but I think it is good to first know and understand the basics before starting to use magic

Answer (score 0):

Example: `<img src="{!! asset('upload/file.jpg') !!}">` will return the correct url to your img.

If you use asset() helper function, the url is generated by `app('url')`, which returns a `UrlGenerator class`.

asset() helper function looks like:

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
}
```

There other helper functions in laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#available-methods), take a look for inspiration